# Automatically populate fields on Email form after email is sent from Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I configured a workflow for auto-populating some fields on Email form after the e-mail is sent from Outlook (I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 for Microsoft Office Outlook). When I send mail as "System Administrator", the fields are populated as expected. But it is not working for users that have "Salesperson" role.

It looks like "Salesperson" role don't have some privileges on Email entity, right?

But under Settings->Administration->Security Roles->Salesperson I don't see the Email entity at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails are a type of Activity.  Phone Calls, Appointments, and Tasks are also Activities.  Security Roles only have the option of modifying Activity-level permissions so you will affect security across all of the above and even more like Case Resolution and Campaign Responses, etc.

Check your workflow.  You should make sure your Scope is set to "Organization".  If it is set to "User" it will only run for the owning user's records.

Comment: Setting the Workflow's Scope to "Organization" did the job. Thank you